# How to flip the screen in Yocto Linux build?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto

I am working on the custom build Yocto Linux running on Wayland, but I do not know how to flip the screen horizontally, as I don't see xrandr in it (I did find xorg.conf). Can someone help on this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Wayland does not use X server see this graphic

[image: Wayland compositor and its clients use EGL to draw directly into the framebuffer]

Wayland and its clients use EGL to draw directly into the framebuffer. It can be a foundation for on overlaying X but it does not have to.

For Wayland Weston there is a solution in https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors/How-can-I-rotate-Wayland-weston/m-p/695720 :

> I found the device name at "/var/log/weston.log".  And I add these
> lines to  "/etc/xdg/weston/weston.ini" :
>
> (My default screen size :1024x768 and 60Hz)
>
> ```
> [output]
> name=fbdev
> mode=768x1024@60
> transform=270
> ```
>
> You can set "transform" 90 or 270 to use your display vertical.

Weston is also intended to replace X on embedded systems (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(display_server_protocol)) :

https://archive.fosdem.org/2020/schedule/event/fbdev/attachments/slides/3595/export/events/attachments/fbdev/slides/3595/fosdem_2020_nicolas_caramelli_linux_framebuffer.pdf  - **Back to the framebuffer !**